# Linkerd proxies metrics reset

Tags: microservices, metrics, linkerd, servicemesh

Good evening,

I’m a student from the university of Rome Tor Vergata. I’m currently working on my master thesis that involves the use of Linkerd.
Very briefly the thesis is about implementing a totally distributed root cause localization system for microservices architectures.
In the metrics collection phase I'm facing an issue with Linkerd since I’m not using Prometheus, but manually scraping metrics from proxies through the /metrics endpoint.
I can’t understand how or when do Linkerd’s proxies reset the various metrics they collect.
Does anybody know if they have a timer? Or is there a way to make them reset metrics after the scraping?

Thanks in advance for any help anyone will give me.

Answer (score 1):

The metrics are stored in memory by the Linkerd proxy as soon as the proxy process starts running.

Most of the metrics are buckets for histograms whose main purpose is to view the data over time, so there isn't a way to reset them and they don't reset themselves.

You could write prometheus queries to select windows of time where you would reset the metrics or you could restart the containers and write queries to filter the metrics on the newer workloads.